# Convert all instances of "\" to "\\" in System::String^ and convert to char*

Tags: string, visual-c++

I have an `openFileDialog` that returns a filename. I want to save that filename as a char* so that I can open it later using `fstream`. To do this I'll need to replace all instances of `\` with `\\` in the string.

My tactic for doing this is to split the `System::String^` on every instance of `\`, and then join all the elements of the resulting `System::String^` array back together with `\\` separating them.

This is the function that I have written, but it seems to return a blank string even when I pass a String^ that contains `\`.

```
private: const char* getCharPointer(String^ name){

    array<String^>^ words;
    String^ delimStr = "\\";
    array<Char>^ delimiter = delimStr->ToCharArray( );
    String^ replaceDelim = "\\\\";

    words = name->Split(delimiter);

    String^ tidiedName = String::Join( replaceDelim, words );
    label1->Text = tidiedName;
    std::string newname=msclr::interop::marshal_as< std::string >( tidiedName);

    const char* name_cstr = newname.c_str();

    return name_cstr;
}
```

I am a newcomer to Visual C++ and Windows in general so I would appreciate any pointers on this. It doesn't help that `IntelliSense` doesn't seem to work with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

`Intellisense` is not provided in VC++ and It seems it will never be added into VC++. 
Anyway, you can use, instead of `Join`, `Replace`.
You can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the reference.

Look at this simple program [ I'm using a `Windows Form Application` and this code is under a `button event handler`].

```
String^ a = "Hello\\World";

String^ b = a->Replace("\\", "\\\\"); //Replace \ with \\
MessageBox::Show(a + " -> " + b);
```

if you run it, you will get this output.

```
Hello\World -> Hello\\World
```

I hope this one is what you need for your code!